# How to work Ruby on Rails + Passenger along with other services (like phpmyadmin/bugzilla) on CentOS 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

My requirement is to access *http://myhost/* for my ROR project and access phpmyadmin and bugzilla using *http://myhost/phpmyadmin/* and *http://myhost/bugzilla/*.

I wonder how to configure my VirtualHost and DocumentRoot, thanks for your comments!

Content of my **/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf**

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.14/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.14
PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby
.....
.....

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName myhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myProject/public
  RailsEnv development
  <Directory /var/www/html/myProject/public>
    AllowOverride All
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 13):

After digging the Passenger documents, I find there is a simple way to do so

```xml
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName myhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myProject/public
  RailsEnv development
  <Directory /var/www/html/myProject/public>
    AllowOverride All
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
  Alias /blog /var/www/html/phpmyadmin
  <Location /phpmyadmin>
    PassengerEnabled off
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

This will enforce Passenger to skip request under path /phpmyadmin

Comment: +1 Ah thanks! you saved me hours! wish I could accept that answer :)

Comment: What does the 'Alias /blog ...' line do?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, and with least amount of headaches would to just create subdomains for phpmyadmin and bugzilla. Then, just create a new virutalhost for each subdomain.

But, if your setup is necessary this seems like I possible solution.

http://macdiggs.com/2007/06/29/using-php-inside-rails-structure-on-apache/